# Can't create paging in razor view page using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I try to create paging in my MVC4 project:

Here the code in razor view page:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body class="wide comments example">
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Position
                </th>
                <th>
                    Office
                </th>
                <th>
                    Age
                </th>
                <th>
                    Start date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Salary
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Tiger Nixon
                </td>
                <td>
                    System Architect
                </td>
                <td>
                    Edinburgh
                </td>
                <td>
                    61
                </td>
                <td>
                    2011/04/25
                </td>
                <td>
                    $320,800
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Garrett Winters
                </td>
                <td>
                    Accountant
                </td>
                <td>
                    Tokyo
                </td>
                <td>
                    63
                </td>
                <td>
                    2011/07/25
                </td>
                <td>
                    $170,750
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Ashton Cox
                </td>
                <td>
                    Junior Technical Author
                </td>
                <td>
                    San Francisco
                </td>
                <td>
                    66
                </td>
                <td>
                    2009/01/12
                </td>
                <td>
                    $86,000
                </td>
          </tbody>
    </table>
    @section Scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').dataTable();
            });

        </script>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code in Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Bundle BundleConfig:

```
 public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on Bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254725
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
    }
```

I try to make paging on table described above in view razor page,but it's no working.

It's works only if I delete this row from Layout page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

and add this rows in razor view page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

insted of this rows:

```
    @section Scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#example').dataTable();
            });

        </script>
```

Any idea why I can't create paging in the table when I use **@scripts.render( /bundles/jquery )** in Layout page?What do I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: any console errors???

Comment: You don't appear to be including `jquery.dataTables.js` in your bundles

Comment: remove `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>` and put all other script tags inside `@section Scripts {}`

Comment: @Ex,No console errors

Comment: @Michael...when you include datatable.js in layout and not on view itself then there is any console errors coming????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of bundles is to package commonly used JS files into a single download (with automatic minimisation etc). This allows more efficient load-times and better caching by the browser.

You need to work with the bundles and not against them. To that end you should download the relevant script files and place them in your scripts folder. Then reference them in a bundle (in this instance I added it to the jQuery bundle for simplicity):

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
                ));
```

Any page-specific scripts would typically then go in a scripts section on the page:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        });

    </script>
}
```

Typically if a downloaded JS file does not have a version in the filename I will rename it to include the version. This make maintenance easier:

e.g. rename `jquery.dataTables.min.js` to `jquery.dataTables-1.10.2.js`

and change the bundle to:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables-{version}.js"
                ));
```

While debugging you would typically have the following at the end of the BundleConfig.cs file:

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

This will ensure all JS files are injected without minification *and* as separate files.

If possible, try to obtain the full JS files for add-ins as well as the .min versions. Bundling will automatically choose the correct version based on `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` (and being able to debug into plugins is *very* useful).